# How to use pre-filled SQLite database in Ionic2?

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic2

I saw that Ionic2 support SqlStorage and only for table creation, I don't know how to use pre-filled sqlite db with SqlStorage.
Can any help me about this?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

When creating your storage, you can pass in an options object

```
let storage = new Storage(SqlStorage, options);
```

The SqlStorage service supports these options:

```
let options = {
  name: '__ionicstorage',              // the name of the database
  backupFlag: SqlStorage.BACKUP_LOCAL, // where to store the file
  existingDatabase: false              // load this as an existing database
};
```

So, you should set `existingDatabase` to true, make sure the `name` matches your database, and set the `backupFlag` to point to the correc location.

The relevant docs are here:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/SqlStorage/

The source is also quite easy to follow: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/ionic/platform/storage/sql.ts

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. The relevant docs aren't mention about the `options`.
But I have another question, what is the location for existing database? In ionic1, I place it inside `www` folder`.